# Java BufferedImage resolution

Tags: java, image, resolution

I'm writing a tool in Java to handle uploaded files in my web sites. I'd like to manage images in a particular way: if the size is bigger than the limit, I'd like, first, to resize the image and then check again the size. Naturally I don't want to do useless work, so I'd like to estimate the size of the image before resiz it. At the moment, I use a BufferedImage to store in memory the image but I can't find the way to know the resolution.
Anyway, can you help me find the right way solve this problem?

My problem is to know in advance the size in bytes of the resized image. I don't want to do the resize if the final byte size is still over a limit set by the user of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Size?  Size in pixels (should be some simple math) or bytes?  For the latter, create a ByteArrayOutputStream and use that as the OutputStream handed to ImageIO.write().  The size will be (something like) baos.toByteArray().length.

I am guessing you intend to do all this resizing on the client side, since doing it after upload would make little sense.

Comment: My problem is to know in advance the size in bytes of the resized image. I don't want to do the resize if the final byte size is still over a limit set by the user of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Is the idea that you want to know the dimensions *before* you put it in a buffered image? Otherwise, you can probably get away with using getWidth() and getHeight() on the buffered image, and perform a resize based on how much too large they are. Set a PREFERRED_SIZE constant, and resize based on how much too large the image is relative to that. You should only ever need to perform one resize.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?: [Checking Image Resolution from Java Applications](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/check-image-resolution-in-java)

Comment: There is difference between height width and resolution.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by resolution. Here, I meant pixel resolution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_resolution#Pixel_resolution